# Wordpress : google map multiple markers change upon sidebar links in accordion

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, google-maps, accordion

I'm using wordpress with jupiter theme and visual composer to build an online agenda of things to do in my city.

We want a page where you can see in a few clicks where all the venues are located.

What I'm trying to do is to have an accordion on the left hand-side and a map (google map?) on the right hand-side.
The accordion would split the venues into categories (theatres, music venues, exhibitions etc..). After clicking on, for example, "theatre", we'd see the names of all the theatres underneath, and the different markers location on the map.
So the markers on the map would change and adapt according to the category of the accordion we'd click on.

It's kinda something like that : http://www.xn--bilan-de-comptences-nzb.fr/listing.php?region=aquitaine&departement=33&ville_cp=33000&page=1
When clicking on "suivant", it goes to an other page. I want to do more or less the same but on a single page.

Html and css aren't the problem, I know how php and mysql work but I'm no expert. I have little knowledge of javascript and jquery.

Thanks for your time and help !

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a similar code earlier for Maps and you can play around and do the tables if you need it.

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:auto;height:500px">
```

You add this div inside the page or section where you want to add the Map. Use VC html element and Change the dimensions as you want**

Create a file called "Maps.js" and include the following code;

Using the site http://www.latlong.net/ you get the Lat & Long details and change var markers info according to your location. Rememver to save the js file in the js folder on your WordPress theme installation folder.

Let me know how it goes!

```
jQuery(function($) {
        // Asynchronously Load the map API 
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize";
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    });

    function initialize() {
        var map;
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var mapOptions = {
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        };

        // Display a map on the page
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
        map.setTilt(45);

        // Multiple Markers
        var markers = [
            ['Church Cross' , 6.027207, 80.216655],
            ['Middle Street', 6.027960, 80.216687],
            ['Lighthouse Street' , 6.026529, 80.216688]
            ['Court Square' , 6.027110, 80.219057]
        ];

        // Info Window Content
        var infoWindowContent = [
            ['<div class="info_content">' +
            '<b>Church Cross</b><br><br>' +
            '<p>No: 9,</p><p>Church Cross St,</p><p>Galle,</p><p>Sri Lanka.</p>' +        '</div>'],
            ['<div class="info_content">' +
            '<b>Middle Street</b><br><br>' +
            '<p>No.5, Middle Street,</p><p>Galle,</p><p>Sri Lanka.</p>' +
            '</div>'],
            ['<div class="info_content">' +
            '<b>Lighthouse Street</b><br><br>' +
            '<p>No.5, Middle Street,</p><p>Galle,</p><p>Sri Lanka.</p>' +
            '</div>']
            ['<div class="info_content">' +
            '<b>Court Square</b><br><br>' +
            '<p>No.1, Court Square,</p><p>Galle,</p><p>Sri Lanka.</p>' +
            '</div>']
        ];

        // Display multiple markers on a map
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

        // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
        for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
            var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
            bounds.extend(position);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: position,
                map: map,
                title: markers[i][0]
            });

            // Allow each marker to have an info window    
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));

            // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }

        // Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
        var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
            this.setZoom(17);
            google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
        });

    }
```